# Prove $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ is regulated

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ be regulated and non-negative. Prove that $g:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ is regulated.

> A function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is a regulated function if $\forall$ $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists$  a step function $\varphi:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ such that $\Vert f-\varphi\Vert<\varepsilon$.

I've tried to use the definition of a regulated function but haven't been able to make any progress. Is there a way of using the fact that a linear combination of regulated functions is regulated? Or am I not even close?

@Arthur Is this attempt at all correct or at least along the lines of what you mean:

We have a step function $\varphi_f$ for $f$ and $\varepsilon_f$. Let $\sqrt{\varphi_f}=\varphi_g$.

We know $\Vert f-\varphi_f\Vert<\varepsilon_f \implies \Vert f-\varphi_g^2\Vert<\varepsilon_f$

$\implies \Vert (\sqrt{f}+\varphi_g)(\sqrt{f}-\varphi_g)\Vert<\varepsilon_f$

$\implies \Vert (g+\varphi_g)\Vert \Vert(g-\varphi_g)\Vert<\varepsilon_f $

$\implies \Vert(g-\varphi_g)\Vert < (\varepsilon_f)/\Vert (g+\varphi_g)\Vert $

So letting $\varepsilon_g = (\varepsilon_f)/\Vert (g+\varphi_g)\Vert $ proves that $\Vert(g-\varphi_g)\Vert < \varepsilon_g$ and hence $g(x)$ is regulated.

Comment: I am a bit naive perhaps... Could you use $\phi=\sqrt{\psi}$ as step function for $g$, for each $\epsilon$ you have, since $\phi$ will obviously be a step function as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $f([a,b]) \subset [0,R]$ for some $R > 0$ and that $[0,R] \to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is **uniformly** continuous.

Finally, you should use that if $\varphi$ is a (non-negative) step function, then so is $\sqrt{\varphi}$.

Of course, you will have to show that the step function $\varphi$ approximating $f$ can be taken to be nonnegative, but this is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Given an $\varepsilon_g$ for $g$, you need to transform it into a fitting $\varepsilon_f$ for $f$. Then, since $f$ is regulated, there is a step function $\varphi_f$ for $f$ and $\varepsilon_f$. This step function can then be transformed into a step function $\varphi_g$ for $g$ and $\varepsilon_g$.

These are the general lines along which you should write your proof. Details about exactly what transformations are involved, along with a final confirmation that $\varphi_g$ actually works must be supplied.

Comment: is my new attempt close? I'm a bit unsure I'm allowed to do what I did.

Comment: @john.smith It's close, but in some sense you've got it backward. You cannot start with $\varepsilon_f$ and $\varphi_f$, and from there say what $\varepsilon_g$ should be. You have to start with an unspecified $\varepsilon_g$, and then say what $\varepsilon_f$ must be for it all to work out. Also remember that there is no $\varphi_f$ until you've decided on what $\varepsilon_f$ should be, which means that no $\varphi$ of any kind should appear in the definition of $\varepsilon_f$.

Comment: That being said, while working backwards won't give you a working proof, it can in many cases give hints about what values do work. In many cases you see a proof that takes some random definition seemingly out of thin air, but somehow it magically works out in the end. Working backwards is one way of getting at those definitions, although it's not mentioned in the final proof.